# Bot Framework AdaptiveDialog: Only trigger activity if the dialog is on top of the stack?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following "[AdaptiveDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)"-style root dialog in Bot Framework v4:

```
public class CustomRootDialog : AdaptiveDialog
{
    public CustomRootDialog() : base(nameof(CustomRootDialog))
    {
        Recognizer = new RegexRecognizer()
        {
            Intents = new List<IntentPattern>()
            {
                new IntentPattern() { Intent = "HelpIntent", Pattern = "(?i)help" },
                new IntentPattern() { Intent = "SecondaryDialog", Pattern = "(?i)run" },
            },
        };
        
        Triggers.Add(new OnIntent("HelpIntent", actions: new List<Dialog>()
        {
            new SendActivity("Hi, here's the help from the root!")
        }));

        Triggers.Add(new OnIntent("SecondaryDialog", actions: new List<Dialog>()
        {
            new SecondaryDialog()
        }));
    }
}
```

When user starts a conversation with the bot and says "help", the dialog answers as expected:

[image: Initial situation]

I also have an another dialog which can be started using the "run"-keyword. Here's the another dialog:

```
public class SecondaryDialog : Dialog
{
    public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var input = dc.Context.Activity.Text;

        if (input == "help")
        {
            await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Secondary dialog help", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return EndOfTurn;
        }

        if (input == "exit")
        {
            return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Complete);
        }

        return EndOfTurn;
    }
}
```

Now when user moves to the second dialog using "run" and then types "help", both the dialogs answer:

[image: Problem with multiple dialogs]

I expected that only the secondary dialog would answer. I can see from the secondary dialog that its Context.Responsed is true, which means I could skip the SendActivity from the secondary dialog. But I want to do the opposite: the root dialog should answer only if the dialog currently on top of the stack hasn't answered.

Is it possible to modify the AdaptiveDialog's trigger so that it only triggers if either no other dialog has responded or if there are no other dialogs running?

**Update:**

The bot is created using the guide provided by Microsoft's docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-setup?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Here's how the bot is registered:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
        ComponentRegistration.Add(new DialogsComponentRegistration());
        ComponentRegistration.Add(new AdaptiveComponentRegistration());

        services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();
        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBot, DialogBot<CustomRootDialog>>();
```

...

```
public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler
    where T : Dialog
{
    private readonly DialogManager DialogManager;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;

    public DialogBot(T rootDialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;

        DialogManager = new DialogManager(rootDialog);
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Activity.");
        await DialogManager.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running `CustomRootDialog` through a dialog manager?

Comment: @KyleDelaney thank you for the question. Yep, there's dialog manager. The code is based on the guidance provided by Microsoft. I updated the question with few more details :)

Comment: Have you read [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-dialog-interruptions#interruptions)? It certainly looks like your desired behavior is already the built-in behavior for adaptive dialogs. It says when the "allow interruptions" property is true, the most immediate parent is checked for triggers before any ancestors are checked. Is it an option make `SecondaryDialog` an adaptive dialog or does it need to be its own type? Adaptive dialogs seem to be designed to have adaptive dialogs all the way down, so things could get hacky otherwise.

Comment: Are you still working on this?